# selectOneMenu does not show values

Tags: jsf, myfaces, selectonemenu

Hi I have the following snipples:

SimController:

```
 private static List<SelectItem> userList;

 public List<SelectItem> getUserList(String Id) {
    try {
        userList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        userList = PDAO.getUserList(Id);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return userList;
}

public void setUserList(List<SelectItem> userlist){
    this.userlist = userlist;
}
```

PDAO:

```
 public static List<SelectItem> getUserList(String Id) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    String sqlCmdName = "sql_get_other_users";
    String sql = getSql(sqlCmdName);
    sql = Util.prepareSqlExt(sql, new String[] { Id });
    return (List<SelectItem>) buildResultSet(new ConverterToUserList(), sqlCmdName, sql);
}


 class ConverterToUserList implements ResultSetConverterInterface {

public Object convertResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    List<SelectItem> userList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        userList.add(new SelectItem(resultSet.getString(1)));

    }
    if (userList.isEmpty())
        return null;
    return userList;
}
 }
```

Html:

```
 <t:div styleClass="#{SimController.simTabName=='SIMULATION_USERS'?'tabPaneActive':'tabPane'}">
                <h:commandButton style="width: 120px !important;" id="TabId3" value="#{messages.tab_other_user}" action="#{SimController.goOtherUsers}" immediate="true" onclick="wait2();">
                    <f:param name="id" value="#{pSimController.details.Id}" />
                </h:commandButton>
            </t:div>



 <h:selectOneMenu styleClass="linkButtons" value="SimController.userListtry"  onchange="document.getElementById('SimFormId:mdsTabId3').click();">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="-" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{SimController.userList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The values I get when I print out the userlist at the latest possible moment i.e. before they are past the the html is:

```
  [javax.faces.model.SelectItem@13a89211, javax.faces.model.SelectItem@46c92ce7, javax.faces.model.SelectItem@7dbe8fcb, javax.faces.model.SelectItem@4a3d1f6a, javax.faces.model.SelectItem@1d522426]
```

which to me looks fine but I always get the following message

```
 org.apache.myfaces.shared.util.SelectItemsIterator hasNext
 WARNING: ValueExpression #{SimController.userList} of UISelectItems with component-path {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /pages/pSim.xhtml][Class: org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.Document,Id: appId][Class: org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.DocumentBody,Id: appBodyId][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid,Id: j_id_t][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup,Id: j_id_1u][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid,Id: j_id_1v][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup,Id: j_id_1z][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid,Id: j_id_20][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectOneMenu,Id: j_id_28][Class: javax.faces.component.UISelectItems,Id: j_id_2a]} does not reference an Object of type SelectItem, array, Iterable or Map, but of type: null

 org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase renderChildren
 WARNING: PanelGrid {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /pages/pSim.xhtml][Class: org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.Document,Id: appId][Class: org.apache.myfaces.custom.document.DocumentBody,Id: appBodyId][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid,Id: j_id_t][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup,Id: j_id_1u][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid,Id: j_id_1v][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup,Id: j_id_1z][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGrid,Id: j_id_20] Location: /pages/planung/inc/buttonStripBottomSimul.xhtml at line 3 and column 55} has not enough children. Child count should be a multiple of the columns attribute.
```

The menu is shown on the html page but it is empty.

Any idea on why this is the case??

Thanks for all your help.

Viking

Comment: where are you printing the list? I don't see code for that. 
Is it because SimController don't have a getter for userList?

Comment: It says getUserList in SimController above... am I missing something?

Comment: Getters don't take method arguments. You have a `public List<SelectItem> getUserList(String Id)`, but you should have a `public List<SelectItem> getUserList()` method.

Comment: @BalusC  Wow thanks.. didn't know you can't do that.. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @balusc already pointed out, try `<f:selectItems value="#{SimController.getUserList(id)}"` from the facelet, if you can access the `id`, which I guess would be `#{pSimController.details.Id}`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't close the question from a comment... here is credit to @BalusC

Getters don't take method arguments. You have a public List getUserList(String Id), but you should have a public List getUserList() method. – BalusC 7 mins ago

Thanks for your help